# Mapping an array into defined segments/fields

Tags: c#

I have an array of type `double[]` that I would like to be able to map into predefined segments. Each segment pertains to a set of `double` values that can be serialized to and from an arbitrary type via a custom type adapter. For instance, consider the following array:

```
var data = new double[] {
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,   // DayOfWeek (Deserializes to DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
  0.5,                   // Deserializes to double
  0.3, 0.7,              // Deserializes to Tuple<double,double>
};
```

With that data, I'd like to be able to split each set of array elements into appropriate `Memory<double>` objects.

My current plan is to have three wrapper structs: `Field`, `FieldSet`, and `MappedArray`, which are currently defined like so (but still a work in progress):

```
public readonly struct Field
{
   public readonly Guid Id;
   public readonly string Name;
   public readonly double Value;
   private readonly int _hash;

   public Field( string name )
   {
     Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     Name = name;
     Value = default;

     _hash = Name.GetHashCode();
   }

   private Field( Field template, double value )
   {
     Id = template.Id;
     Name = template.Name;
     Value = value;

     _hash = template._hash;
   }
}

public struct FieldSet
{
  public readonly Guid Id;
  public readonly string Name;
  public readonly Field[] Fields;
  private readonly Memory<double> _data;
  private readonly int _hash;

  public double this[ int index ] => _data[ index ];

  public Field this[ string name ]
  {
    get => throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public Field this[ Field field ]
  {
    get => throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public FieldSet( string name, Field[] fields )
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Name = name;
    Fields = fields;

    _data = null;
    _hash = name.GetHashCode();
  }

  private FieldSet( FieldSet template, Memory<double> data )
  {
    Id = template.Id;
    Name = template.Name;
    fields = template.Fields;

    _data = data;
    _hash = template._hash;
  }
}

public struct MappedArray
{
  private Memory<double> _data;

  public double this[ int index ] => _data[ index ];

  public FieldSet this[ string name ]
  { // Lookup via name
    get => throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public FieldSet this[ FieldSet set ]
  { // Lookup via Id
    get => throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

With those, I have a few goals:

- Bi-directional. E.g. can take the types and convert them into a double[] array. This is less of a priority and out of scope for this question, but something that may be helpful to consider.
- Ability to index `FieldSet`s and `Field`s by their name, index, and by Id (something that avoids string comparison for performance)
- **Avoid allocation at all costs, unless it is unavoidable** (e.g. be able to reuse `Field/FieldSet` if possible.

The second goal is what I am struggling the most with. This mapping system will be running on a **VERY hot code path** (neural network input/output in real-time) and I'm worried that the GC is going to have a tough time with all of the allocation and deallocation, so I'd like to reuse `Field` and `FieldSet` as much as possible, since their purpose is to abstract the array into an easy-to-consume structure.

With that, the main question is: How can I design this so that the "schema" structure can be re-used? Essentially, have static `FieldSet` and `Field` instances that define the schema, and then have the ability to access those segments, all without having to allocate and deallocate. With @Pressacco's reply below, the flyweight pattern comes to mind, where `FieldSet` and `Field` are recycled, and a `Memory<double>` is attached.

Comment: Just to play rubber duck: What in your current plans would be a) likely to not perform good enough for the consuming hot code path (a code example of the consuming code might be of interest), and b) likely not be easy enough for the developer using this system (if so, why)?

Comment: A) With the current (and unfinished) design, a lot of copying occurs. Ideally, the design would not have to do any copying whatsoever; just properly split a provided array and match it with existing instances. Those two classes are structs, so they'll be copied byval anyways, so a class might be a better idea. Also, @Pressacco's reply has the right idea. The Flyweight pattern sounds like a good candidate.

B) That was awkwardly worded on my part. I just mean to have it abstracted so that a developer can use a `Field/Set`. I'm doing an awful job of explaining, so you can just ignore that part

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means the answer, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

### Deserialization

I would start by taking a look at the `System.Runtime` namespace.  Specifically the `StructLayout` attribute in [System.Runtime.InteropServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netframework-4.8).  A couple of notes:

- Consider creating a sandbox application to ensure that you are getting the expected performance.
- `StructLayout` has it's limitations... make sure that they don't impact you.

### Performance

Consider creating a resource pool where you recycle object instances.  If you are not allocating & de-allocating memory... then you won't have that performance hit.  I believe the design pattern may be called an [Object Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

The pseudocode would look something like

```
var message = resourcePool.GetInstance();
MessageFactory.Create(message, serializedData);
...
// do work
...
resourcePool.ReturnInstance(message); // the allocated memory can now be used to de-serialize a future message
```

Lastly, try to avoid doing pre-mature performance optimization.